# Putting mysql database on server Using java

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

Im new to setting up databases on sever but i have experience in working on databases.

I wanted to put my MYSQL database on a server and connect it so my java program could be accessed from anywhere by those who have it. I heard my school teacher saying something like i need a servlet to get the connection? I've researched servelet's. However, what i dont get is where this servlet should be saved. On the java folder, or on the server? Or is it as simple as running phpmyadmin on my server so tables can be acessed from it and having the servers root in the javadb connection instead of the local host?

Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question.

Comment: It's not a stupid question, just a misconception about having a MySQL database server together with your application. In short, you *can't* port your application with a MySQL database server, instead you can have a sql script that will create your MySQL database on localhost (or where the database server will be) and have some configuration in your web.xml file or other files that will tell your Java app how to connect with the database server: server name, user, password and other parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access/modify the data in your MySQL database from anywhere you will need some software components:

- A database Server, that will host your MySQL Database.
- A Servlet Container, that will host the Java Programs (i.e. Servlets) that will modify/access the data in your Database. This Server must have internet connection so you can access it from anywhere.
- A package (a.k.a WAR) with all the Servlets you need for your applications. Let's say you need to insert a row in a table, you need to built a Servlet for that. Also if you want to run a Query an show a result for that in Screen.

You can have all the containers in one PC's or you can use several cloud platforms that offers all this components on the Web for free (except the Servlets, you have to code that).